# Why is integer assignment on a naturally aligned variable atomic on x86?

Tags: c++, concurrency, x86, atomic, memory-alignment

I've been reading [this article](http://preshing.com/20130618/atomic-vs-non-atomic-operations/) about atomic operations, and it mentions 32-bit integer assignment being atomic on x86, as long as the variable is naturally aligned.

Why does natural alignment assure atomicity?

Comment: And this question is the first result :-)

Comment: ..and my dup above is the second:)

Comment: The dupe doesn't explain why this guarantees atomicity.

Comment: @timlyo Oops. You're correct on that one. I'll try to vote to reopen. And I don't understand the downvote. I've also tagged x86 as this is more to do with chip architecture than a specific programming language.

Comment: To be fair the question "what is natural alignment" is easily answered on google. It was probably due to that. Thanks.

Comment: You need to ask intel about that

Comment: @user3528438: that's not particularly helpful.

Comment: @Bathsheba This is highly implementation dependent behavior, on the ISA and silicon level. If you ask GCC developer this question, they will redirect you to the silicon venders, too, Ibelieve.

Comment: The answer is in the very next sentence. "You can verify it by consulting your processor manual and/or compiler documentation."

Comment: The whole answer to the question is "because the CPU documentation says so". Why make it more complicated?

Comment: Why is this question tagged with C or C++? It's about particular CPU operations, isn't it?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

**"Natural" alignment means aligned to its own type width**.  Thus, the load/store will never be split across any kind of boundary wider than itself (e.g. page, cache-line, or an even narrower chunk size used for data transfers between different caches).

CPUs often do things like cache-access, or cache-line transfers between cores, in power-of-2 sized chunks, so alignment boundaries smaller than a cache line do matter.  (See @BeeOnRope's comments below).  See also [Atomicity on x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38447226/atomicity-on-x86) for more details on how CPUs implement atomic loads or stores internally, and [Can num++ be atomic for 'int num'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39393850/can-num-be-atomic-for-int-num) for more about how atomic RMW operations like `atomic<int>::fetch_add()` / `lock xadd` are implemented internally.

---

First, this assumes that the `int` is updated with a single store instruction, rather than writing different bytes separately.  This is part of what `std::atomic` guarantees, but that plain C or C++ doesn't.  It will *normally* be the case, though.  The [x86-64 System V ABI](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI) doesn't forbid compilers from making accesses to `int` variables non-atomic, even though it does require `int` to be 4B with a default alignment of 4B.  For example, `x = a<<16 | b` could compile to two separate 16-bit stores if the compiler wanted.

Data races are Undefined Behaviour in both C and C++, so compilers can and do assume that memory is not asynchronously modified.  **For code that is guaranteed not to break, use C11 [stdatomic](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic) or C++11 [std::atomic](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic).  Otherwise the compiler will just keep a value in a register [instead of reloading every time your read it](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/387181/mcu-programming-c-o2-optimization-breaks-while-loop#387478)**, like `volatile` but with actual guarantees and official support from the language standard.

Before C++11, atomic ops were usually done with `volatile` or other things, and a healthy dose of "works on compilers we care about", so C++11 was a huge step forward.  Now you no longer have to care about what a compiler does for plain `int`; just use `atomic<int>`.  If you find old guides talking about atomicity of `int`, they probably predate C++11.  [When to use volatile with multi threading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557979/when-to-use-volatile-with-multi-threading/58535118#58535118) explains why that works in practice, and that `atomic<T>` with `memory_order_relaxed` is the modern way to get the same functionality.

```
std::atomic<int> shared;  // shared variable (compiler ensures alignment)

int x;           // local variable (compiler can keep it in a register)
x = shared.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
shared.store(x, std::memory_order_relaxed);
// shared = x;  // don't do that unless you actually need seq_cst, because MFENCE or XCHG is much slower than a simple store
```

Side-note: for `atomic<T>` larger than the CPU can do atomically (so `.is_lock_free()` is false), see [Where is the lock for a std::atomic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50298358/where-is-the-lock-for-a-stdatomic).  `int` and `int64_t` / `uint64_t` are lock-free on all the major x86 compilers, though.

---

Thus, we just need to talk about the behaviour of an instruction like `mov [shared], eax`.

---

**TL;DR: The x86 ISA guarantees that naturally-aligned stores and loads are atomic, up to 64bits wide.**  So compilers can use ordinary stores/loads as long as they ensure that `std::atomic<T>` has natural alignment.

(But note that i386 `gcc -m32` fails to do that for C11 `_Atomic` 64-bit types inside structs, only aligning them to 4B, so `atomic_llong` can be non-atomic in some cases.  https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65146#c4).  `g++ -m32` with `std::atomic` is fine, at least in g++5 because https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65147 was fixed in 2015 by a change to the `<atomic>` header.  That didn't change the C11 behaviour, though.)

---

IIRC, there were SMP 386 systems, but the current memory semantics weren't established until 486.  This is why the manual says "486 and newer".

From the "Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer Manuals, volume 3", with *my notes in italics*.   (see also the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki for links: [current versions](https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) of all volumes, or direct link to [page 256 of the vol3 pdf from Dec 2015](https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-system-programming-manual-325384.pdf#page=256))

In x86 terminology, a "word" is two 8-bit bytes.  32 bits are a double-word, or DWORD.

> ###Section 8.1.1 Guaranteed Atomic Operations

> The Intel486 processor (and newer processors since) guarantees that the following basic memory
> operations will always be carried out atomically:

> - Reading or writing a byte
> - Reading or writing a word aligned on a 16-bit boundary
> - **Reading or writing a doubleword aligned on a 32-bit boundary**  *(This is another way of saying "natural alignment")*

That last point that I bolded is the answer to your question: This behaviour is part of what's required for a processor to be an x86 CPU (i.e. an implementation of the ISA).

---

The rest of the section provides further guarantees for newer Intel CPUs: **Pentium widens this guarantee to 64 bits**.

> The
> Pentium processor (and newer processors since) guarantees that the
> following additional memory operations will always be carried out
> atomically:

> - **Reading or writing a quadword aligned on a 64-bit boundary**
>   *(e.g. x87 load/store of a `double`, or `cmpxchg8b` (which was new in Pentium P5))*
> - 16-bit accesses to uncached memory locations that fit within a 32-bit data bus.

The section goes on to point out that accesses split across cache lines (and page boundaries) are not guaranteed to be atomic, and:

> "An x87 instruction or an SSE instructions that accesses data larger than a quadword may be implemented using
> multiple memory accesses."

---

#### AMD's manual agrees with Intel's about aligned 64-bit and narrower loads/stores being atomic

So integer, x87, and MMX/SSE loads/stores up to 64b, even in 32-bit or 16-bit mode (e.g. `movq`, `movsd`, `movhps`, `pinsrq`, `extractps`, etc.) *are* atomic if the data is aligned.  `gcc -m32` uses `movq xmm, [mem]` to implement atomic 64-bit loads for things like `std::atomic<int64_t>`.  Clang4.0 `-m32` unfortunately uses `lock cmpxchg8b` [bug 33109](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=33109).

On some CPUs with 128b or 256b internal data paths (between execution units and L1, and between different caches), 128b and even 256b vector loads/stores are atomic, but this is *not* guaranteed by any standard or easily queryable at run-time, [unfortunately for compilers implementing `std::atomic<__int128>` or 16B structs](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2017-01/msg02344.html).

(**Update: x86 vendors [have decided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646018/sse-instructions-which-cpus-can-do-atomic-16b-memory-operations/7647825#7647825) that the AVX feature bit also indicates atomic 128-bit aligned loads/stores**.  Before that we only had https://rigtorp.se/isatomic/ experimental testing to verify it.)

If you want atomic 128b across all x86 systems, you must use `lock cmpxchg16b` (available only in 64bit mode).  (And it wasn't available in the first-gen x86-64 CPUs.  You need to use `-mcx16` with GCC/Clang [for them to emit it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38984153/implement-aba-counter-with-c11-cas/38991835#38991835).)

Even CPUs that internally do atomic 128b loads/stores can exhibit non-atomic behaviour in multi-socket systems with a coherency protocol that operates in smaller chunks:  e.g. [AMD Opteron 2435 (K10) with threads running on separate sockets, connected with HyperTransport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646018/sse-instructions-which-cpus-can-do-atomic-16b-memory-operations/7647825#7647825).

---

**Intel's and AMD's manuals diverge for unaligned access to *cacheable* memory**.  The common subset for all x86 CPUs is the AMD rule.  Cacheable means write-back or write-through memory regions, not uncacheable or write-combining, as set with PAT or MTRR regions.  They don't mean that the cache-line has to already be hot in L1 cache.

- Intel P6 and later guarantee atomicity for cacheable loads/stores up to 64 bits as long as they're within a single cache-line (64B, or 32B on very old CPUs like Pentium III).
- AMD guarantees atomicity for cacheable loads/stores that fit within a single 8B-aligned chunk.  That makes sense, because we know from the 16B-store test on multi-socket [Opteron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opteron) that HyperTransport only transfers in 8B chunks, and doesn't lock while transferring to prevent tearing.  (See above).  I guess `lock cmpxchg16b` must be handled specially.

Possibly related: AMD uses [MOESI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOESI_protocol) to share dirty cache-lines directly between caches in different cores, so one core can be reading from its valid copy of a cache line while updates to it are coming in from another cache.

Intel uses [MESIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESIF_protocol), which requires dirty data to propagate out to the large shared inclusive L3 cache which acts as a backstop for coherency traffic.  L3 is tag-inclusive of per-core L2/L1 caches, even for lines that have to be in the Invalid state in L3 because of being M or E in a per-core L1 cache.  The data path between L3 and per-core caches is only 32B wide in Haswell/Skylake, so it must buffer or something to avoid a write to L3 from one core happening between reads of two halves of a cache line, which could cause tearing at the 32B boundary.

The relevant sections of the manuals:

> **The P6 family processors (and newer Intel** processors
> since) guarantee that the following additional memory operation will
> always be carried out atomically:
>
> - Unaligned 16-, 32-, and 64-bit accesses to cached memory that fit within a cache line.

> **AMD64 Manual 7.3.2 Access Atomicity**
> Cacheable, naturally-aligned single loads or stores of up to a quadword are atomic on any processor
> model, as are misaligned loads or stores of less than a quadword that
> are contained entirely within a naturally-aligned quadword

Notice that AMD guarantees atomicity for any load smaller than a qword, but Intel only for power-of-2 sizes.  32-bit protected mode and 64-bit long mode can load a 48 bit `m16:32` as a memory operand into `cs:eip` with [far-`call`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/CALL.html) or far-`jmp`.  (And far-call pushes stuff on the stack.)  IDK if this counts as a single 48-bit access or separate 16 and 32-bit.

There have been attempts to formalize the x86 memory model, the latest one being [the x86-TSO (extended version) paper from 2009](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Epes20/weakmemory/x86tso-paper.pdf) (link from the memory-ordering section of the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki).  It's not usefully skimmable since they define some symbols to express things in their own notation, and I haven't tried to really read it.  IDK if it describes the atomicity rules, or if it's only concerned with memory *ordering*.

---

#### Atomic Read-Modify-Write

I mentioned `cmpxchg8b`, but I was only talking about the load and the store each separately being atomic (i.e. no "tearing" where one half of the load is from one store, the other half of the load is from a different store).

To prevent the contents of that memory location from being modified *between* the load and the store, you need **`lock`** `cmpxchg8b`, just like you need `lock inc [mem]` for the entire read-modify-write to be atomic.  Also note that even if `cmpxchg8b` without `lock` does a single atomic load (and optionally a store), it's not safe in general to use it as a 64b load with expected=desired.  If the value in memory happens to match your expected, you'll get a non-atomic read-modify-write of that location.

The `lock` prefix makes even unaligned accesses that cross cache-line or page boundaries atomic, but you can't use it with `mov` to make an unaligned store or load atomic.  It's only usable with memory-destination read-modify-write instructions like `add [mem], eax`.

(`lock` is implicit in `xchg reg, [mem]`, so don't use `xchg` with mem to save code-size or instruction count unless performance is irrelevant.  Only use it when you *want* the memory barrier and/or the atomic exchange, or when code-size is the only thing that matters, e.g. in a boot sector.)

See also: *[Can num++ be atomic for 'int num'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39393850/can-num-be-atomic-for-int-num/39396999#39396999)*

---

#### Why `lock mov [mem], reg` doesn't exist for atomic unaligned stores

From the instruction reference manual (Intel x86 manual vol2), `cmpxchg`:

> This instruction can be used with a `LOCK` prefix to allow the
> instruction to be executed atomically. To simplify the interface to
> the processor’s bus, the destination operand receives a write cycle
> without regard to the result of the comparison. The destination
> operand is written back if the comparison fails; otherwise, the source
> operand is written into the destination. (**The processor never produces
> a locked read without also producing a locked write**.)

This design decision reduced chipset complexity before the memory controller was built into the CPU.  It may still do so for `lock`ed instructions on MMIO regions that hit the PCI-express bus rather than DRAM.  It would just be confusing for a `lock mov reg, [MMIO_PORT]` to produce a write as well as a read to the memory-mapped I/O register.

The other explanation is that it's not very hard to make sure your data has natural alignment, and `lock store` would perform horribly compared to just making sure your data is aligned.  It would be silly to spend transistors on something that would be so slow it wouldn't be worth using.  If you really need it (and don't mind reading the memory too), you could use `xchg [mem], reg` (XCHG has an implicit LOCK prefix), which is even slower than a hypothetical `lock mov`.

Using a `lock` prefix is also a full memory barrier, so it imposes a performance overhead beyond just the atomic RMW.  i.e. x86 can't do relaxed atomic RMW (without flushing the store buffer).  Other ISAs can, so using `.fetch_add(1, memory_order_relaxed)` can be faster on non-x86.

Fun fact: Before `mfence` existed, a common idiom was `lock add dword [esp], 0`, which is a no-op other than clobbering flags and doing a locked operation.  `[esp]` is almost always hot in L1 cache and won't cause contention with any other core.  This idiom may still be more efficient than MFENCE as a stand-alone memory barrier, especially on AMD CPUs.

`xchg [mem], reg` is probably the most efficient way to implement a sequential-consistency store, vs. `mov`+`mfence`, on both Intel and AMD.  [`mfence` on Skylake at least blocks out-of-order execution of non-memory instructions, but `xchg` and other `lock`ed ops don't.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50494658/are-loads-and-stores-the-only-instructions-that-gets-reordered/50496379#50496379)  Compilers other than gcc do use `xchg` for stores, even when they don't care about reading the old value.

---

### Motivation for this design decision:

Without it, software would have to use 1-byte locks (or some kind of available atomic type) to guard accesses to 32bit integers, which is hugely inefficient compared to shared atomic read access for something like a global timestamp variable updated by a timer interrupt.  It's probably basically free in silicon to guarantee for aligned accesses of bus-width or smaller.

For locking to be possible at all, some kind of atomic access is required.  (Actually, I guess the hardware could provide some kind of totally different hardware-assisted locking mechanism.)  For a CPU that does 32bit transfers on its external data bus, it just makes sense to have that be the unit of atomicity.

---

Since you offered a bounty, I assume you were looking for a long answer that wandered into all interesting side topics.  Let me know if there are things I didn't cover that you think would make this Q&A more valuable for future readers.

Since you [linked one in the question](http://preshing.com/20130618/atomic-vs-non-atomic-operations/), **I highly recommend reading more of Jeff Preshing's blog posts**.  They're excellent, and helped me put together the pieces of what I knew into an understanding of memory ordering in C/C++ source vs. asm for different hardware architectures, and how / when to tell the compiler what you want if you aren't writing asm directly.

Comment: [AMD64 Manual](http://support.amd.com/TechDocs/24593.pdf#page=224) **7.3.2  Access Atomicity**: "Cacheable, naturally-aligned single loads or stores of up to a quadword are atomic on any processor model, as are misaligned loads or stores of less than a quadword that are contained entirely within a naturally-aligned quadword"

Comment: @bartolo-otrit: hmm, so AMD has stricter requirements for atomicity of cacheable loads/stores than Intel?  That matches up with the fact that [HyperTransport between sockets transfers cache lines in aligned chunks as small as 8B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646018/sse-instructions-which-cpus-can-do-atomic-16b-memory-operations/7647825#7647825).  I wish Intel or someone would document the common subset of functionality that is required for a CPU to be called x86.

Comment: You mention motivation for having atomic accesses at all (i.e., it makes the CPU more functional as a programming target), but I think the question kind of hints at a desire to understand the other half: what is the motivation behind the restriction that only naturally aligned accesses are atomic? I.e., the restriction that per your answer kind of still exists AMD (actually it's "within a quadword", but its kind of close) and existed on Intel in the past. A simple answer would be that it simplifies the design of hardware: the hypertransport example is a good one, but also ...

Comment: ... things like caches that may be designed to deliver aligned chunks and where some unaligned cases would involve reading two aligned chunks and combining them (similarly to a cross-cache line read). It might be worth throwing a line or two in there that all of what you discuss in your answer mostly applies to accesses that "line up", perhaps also including accesses that are fully contained in an earlier one (although "earlier" means you'd need to complicate everything with ordering) - but doesn't apply to partially overlapping accesses, at least not in a simple way since we know ...

Comment: ... that such accesses can combine bytes from two different points in time into a franken-word result (whether that really violates atomicity would require some more formal definitions). BTW, the paper you linked is a good one: I don't think they really address things like atomicity or cache-line splits or anything (at least early versions didn't), but I think you could say they assume atomicity (no tearing) since without atomicity you can't really have a meaningful discussion of ordering (since before/after would now have a "half before/half after" state).

Comment: @BeeOnRope: I got into more into implementation detail on [Atomicity on x86](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38447226).  Good points about cache-access hardware working in aligned qwords.  I added a new 2nd paragraph with some links to more recent answers I've written, and some other updates.  If you have a good idea for an edit, feel free.

Comment: At first, thanks and +1. I was expecting that the manuals would have hints in the instruction set reference (e.g. when describing the `MOV` instruction), and searched for it some time. Although I had found it a while ago, your hint to chapter 8.1 in the manuals is very valuable. However, I've still got a question: This chapter always talks about "two processors", "another bus agent" and so on. Do you know of a chapter which clearly explains what happens with interrupts *on the same* CPU (core / thread), or further references regarding this?

Comment: @Binarus: Interrupts always happen at a boundary between instructions, so on a uniprocessor (or single threaded process with only signal handlers or green threads), every single instruction except `rep movs` or gather load/scatter store is atomic, even `fld m80` or page-split `vmovdqu zmm0, [rdi]`.  See [Is x86 CMPXCHG atomic, if so why does it need LOCK?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27837731) and [Interrupting instruction in the middle of execution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53687178)

Comment: Thank you very much again for showing the reference (it's in the comments in the question you linked). I was always writing assembler parts of my code woth having it in my mind that way  because I had read this information in the i486 reference manual which I still have in printed form :-). However, I didn't spot it until now in the recent manuals ...

Comment: Hi @PeterCordes , I was wondering if you have time to take a look at this related question? thank you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75289169/is-cache-coherency-only-an-issue-when-storing-and-not-when-loading

Answer (score 6):

If a 32-bit or smaller object is naturally-aligned within a "normal" part of memory, it will be possible for any 80386 or compatible processor other than the
80386sx to read or write all 32 bits of the object in a single operation.  While the ability of a platform to do something in a quick and useful fashion doesn't necessarily mean the platform won't sometimes do it in some other fashion for some reason, and while I believe it's possible on many if not all x86 processors to have regions of memory which can only be accessed 8 or 16 bits at a time, I don't think Intel has ever defined any conditions where requesting an aligned 32-bit access to a "normal" area of memory would cause the system to read or write part of the value without reading or writing the whole thing, and I don't think Intel has any intention of ever defining any such thing for "normal" areas of memory.

Comment: I don't think there are any x86 memory-types that split wider accesses, or disallow them.  "uncachable" and "write-combining" memory regions just mean that each N byte load instruction produces a separate request of that width outside the cache hierarchy.  I forget if normal stores can be merged in a "write-combining" region, or if it *only* works for weakly-ordered `movnt` stores.  There might be an obscure memory-type that I'm forgetting about, though.  Besides the normal write-back, there's also write-through.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Intel's processors at least the 80486 and I think beyond are capable of being addressed to RAM with different speeds and bus widths, and I'd be somewhat surprised if that support has not been retained.  On the older processors, when the processor issued a 16-bit memory request it would look for a signal saying that the memory could only support 8-bit requests.  If the processor was hooked to an 8-bit memory system, the hardware would treat the 16-bit request as a request to read or write the bottom half of the word, but would request that the processor follow up with...

Comment: ...an 8-bit access for the other half of it.  The fact that part of the memory is attached to an 8-bit bus rather than a 16-bit bus would be invisible to code (aside from the longer execution time for memory accesses) but if hardware is incapable of acting on more than 8 bits at once there's no way the processor can do things in one step.  I wouldn't be surprised if all of the Intel processors hold the bus between the 8-bit accesses (so as to make the 32-bit sequence effectively atomic except in systems using dual-port RAM) but the operation *must* be split at the hardware level.

Comment: Intel since Nehalem has the DRAM controllers integrated into the CPU, so that interface is fixed at 64 bits wide.  (Or 72 with ECC).  And that width isn't software-visible because nothing else can access RAM without going through the CPU's memory controllers.  I/O accesses go over the frontside bus, which has been through various iterations.  So your basic point still holds, I'd assume, that any hypothetical narrow bus would get locked for the duration of a single access that needs to be atomic.  And yeah, 486 and maybe some later generations likely actually support narrow busses that way.

Answer (score 2):

Naturally aligned means that the address of the type is a multiple of the size of the type.

For example, a byte can be at any address, a short (assuming 16 bits) must be on a multiple of 2, an int (assuming 32 bits) must be on a multiple of 4, and a long (assuming 64 bits) must be on a multiple of 8.

In the event that you access a piece of data that is not naturally aligned the CPU will either raise a fault or will read/write the memory, but not as an atomic operation. The action the CPU takes will depend on the architecture.

For example, image we've got the memory layout below:

```
01234567
...XXXX.
```

and

```
int *data = (int*)3;
```

When we try to read `*data` the bytes that make up the value are spread across 2 int size blocks, 1 byte is in block 0-3 and 3 bytes are in block 4-7. Now, just because the blocks are logically next to each other it doesn't mean they are physically. For example, block 0-3 could be at the end of a cpu cache line, whilst block 3-7 is sitting in a page file. When the cpu goes to access block 3-7 in order to get the 3 bytes it needs it may see that the block isn't in memory and signals that it needs the memory paged in. This will probably block the calling process whilst the OS pages the memory back in.

After the memory has been paged in, but before your process is woken back up another one may come along and write a `Y` to address 4. Then your process is rescheduled and the CPU completes the read, but now it has read XYXX, rather than the XXXX you expected.

Comment: You are implying aligned access is atomic, which may or may not be true, depending on to much unknowns.

Comment: @user3528438 - on x86, for example, a 32bit read is atomic as long as the memory location is naturally aligned.

Comment: Actually regular x86 instructions (not SIMD) do not require data alignment. So no fault.

Comment: @FrancisStraccia - that's correct, they don't require it. However, if they're not naturally aligned then they're not atomic and you can get data shearing. On some architectures, such as Sparc, you will get a fault if you attempt to read incorrectly aligned data.

Comment: then what about 64 bits, or even wider items? what about systems with less than 32bit of memory bus, what if the memory mapped IO bus is even narrower? yeah PC memories are 64 bit per DIMM then we don't need to care about anything else?

Comment: @Sean: I was referring to "...aligned the CPU will either **raise a fault** or will read/write..." in your answer. Given the OP asked about x86 it could have looked confusing. (On other archs yes, faults may happen of course.)

Comment: @FrancisStraccia actually you can turn on alignment checking + hw exceptions on x86.

Comment: This is correct, but doesn't answer the question.  The question is why aligned integer accesses *are* guaranteed atomic **on x86**, not why unaligned accesses are not guaranteed to be atomic.  The answer is that the architecture provides that guarantee for accesses up to 64bits (see my answer for a quote from the x86 ISA manual).

Answer (score 2):

If you were asking why it's designed so, I would say it's a good side product from the design of CPU architecture.

Back in the 486 time, there is no multi-core CPU or QPI link, so atomicity isn't really a strict requirement at that time (DMA may require it?).

On x86, the data width is 32bits (or 64 bits for x86_64), meaning the CPU can read and write up to data width in one shot. And the memory data bus is typically the same or wider than this number. Combined with the fact that reading/writing on aligned address is done in one shot, naturally there is nothing preventing the read/write to be un-atomic. You gain speed/atomic at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question, a variable is naturally aligned if it exists at a memory address that is a multiple of its size.

If we consider only - as the article you linked does - *assignment instructions*, then alignment guarantees atomicity because MOV (the assignment instruction) is atomic by design on aligned data.

Other kinds of instructions, INC for example, need to be **LOCK**ed (an x86 prefix which gives exclusive access to the shared memory to the current processor for the duration of the prefixed operation) even if the data are aligned because they actually execute via multiple steps (=instructions, namely load, inc, store).

Comment: I guess it's because it's essentially link-only. Some "in line" explanation would improve it.

Comment: He asked something very encyclopedic. The answer was trying to answer with the definitions I thought he was looking for. Links are just for "sources". e.g. he did not want to know how LOCK works.

Comment: No. I downvoted this answer, because it is wrong. The compiler _does not_ add a `LOCK` prefix to involved operations. The question was "Why are aligned DWORD `MOV`s atomic. This question has not been answered. Adding a `LOCK` prefix would make all (possible) instructions atomic, because it locks the (memory) bus.

Comment: @zx485: Kinda. Actually only a small number of instruction can even be lock-prefixed. `mov` is not among them.

Comment: @EOF: Yes. That's why I wrote `(possible) instructions`. But if any compiler would add `LOCK` prefixes to all operations considered atomic, every disassembly would look completely different.

Comment: @zx485: INC for example needs to be LOCK'd. The original question was "What does it mean when a variable is naturally aligned, and how does this assure the **operation** is atomic?". **Operation** != MOV. Mov is atomic per se on aligned data, of course.

Comment: I reworded the answer for clarity's sake.

Comment: @Francis Straccia: I retracted my downvote and replaced it by an upvote because of the correct phrase **'is atomic by design'**. The design of x86 guarantees the atomicity of `MOV`s on aligned data. I don't know why - but it's nice. An explanation would be fantastic, but probably there are only a few people in the world who could answer that.

Comment: @zx485: For cached memory, the answer is simple: Cache line size is greater than register size.

Comment: @zx485: I think the answer to the design-decision part of the question is more along the lines of:  It speeds up software for a small investment of transistors.  Without it, software would have to use byte locks (or some kind of available atomic type) to guard accesses to 32bit integers, which is hugely inefficient compared to shared atomic read access.  It's probably basically free in silicon to guarantee for aligned accesses of bus-width or smaller.